# Is it possible to do a contrast in a 2x2 (or more) contingency table or am I completely missing the point?

Tags: chi-squared-test, contrasts

I have the following 2x2 contingency table of observed frequencies:

```
Contingency Table
------------------------------------------
                        Categories
                      --------------
                       Cat 1  Cat 2  Total
------------------------------------------
             Group 1    135    16     151
Participants
             Group 2    241    40     281

               Total    376    56     432
-----------------------------------------
```

The Chi-squared test result is the following:

```
χ2 Tests
--------------------------------
            Value     df     p
--------------------------------
χ2          1.153      1   0.283
N             432
--------------------------------
```

As we can see, the p-value is > .05, therefore there is no statistically significant difference between Group and Type. Therefore, if I'm not mistaken, Group and Type seem not to be related.

However, there might be a statistically significant difference between participants in Group 1 and Group 2 separately in Cat 1 and in Cat 2 (e.g., 135 vs. 241 on the one hand, and between 16 and 40 on the other hand). I am also interested to know if the difference is statistically significant in Group 1 between Cat 1 and Cat 2, and in Group 2 between Cat 1 and Cat 2 (e.g., 135 vs. 16 and 241 vs. 40).

My questions:

- How do I test the differences within each variable?
- Is there an easy (relatively) way to do it?
- Would those be similar to ANOVA's contrasts or am I completely missing the point?

---

Technical details:

- R 4.2.1 GUI 1.79 High Sierra build
- RStudio 2022.07.1 Build 554 for Intel macOS
- macOS Monterey Version 12.5

R/RStudio code (inspired by an example from [ETHZ](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-April/275999.html) in Switzerland):

```
tab <- matrix(c(135, 16, 241, 40), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(tab) <- c('Cat 1', 'Cat 2')
rownames(tab) <- c('Group 1', 'Group 2')
(tab <- as.table(tab))

chisq.test(tab, correct = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, the chi squared test that you ran above is testing whether group and type are independent or dependent - the outcome is that there is not enough evidence to suggest that they are dependent.

> How do I test the differences within each variable?

It's not totally clear to me why you want to do this, but I'll show how to test whether one type is more likely within groups as an example (you could do the same sort of thing to test within-types; you could also test within a single group - this is much easier). It's called a test of homogeneity.
The null hypothesis here is $H_{0}:\ \mathbb{P}(\text{type}=t,\text{group}=g) = 0.5\mathbb{P}(\text{group}={g})$, which basically states that both types are equally likely.

Under $H_0$, the expected numbers in the table become

```
r$> e <- matrix(c(0.5*376, 0.5*376, 0.5*56,0.5*56),nrow=2)

r$> e
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  188   28
[2,]  188   28
```

The formula for the $\chi^2$-statistic is $\sum (o_{ij} - e_{ij})^2/e_{ij}$:

```
r$> o
       Group 1 Group 2
Type 1     135      16
Type 2     241      40

r$> sum((o-e)^2/e)
[1] 40.16869
```

There is a result (if you're interested search for generalized likelihood ratio theorem) that says that this statistic is approximately distributed according to a chi-squared distribution under $H_0$, with degrees of freedom equal to the number of degrees of freedom of $H_0$ (here there is 1 degree of freedom).

The probability of something more extreme is

```
r$> 1 - pchisq(sum((o-e)^2/e),df = 1)
[1] 2.339906e-10
```

so we reject $H_0$, since this probability is very small.

> Is there an easy (relatively) way to do it?

I couldn't find an existing R function to do this, but I'm sure one exists somewhere

> Would those be similar to ANOVA's contrasts or am I completely missing the point?

This is not the same as ANOVA

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You wrote "it's not totally clear why [I] want to do this". Please find hereafter a little background: I did a contingency table in order to find out the prevalence of Categories 1 and 2 (I updated the original post to reflect my comments here). Then, what I would like is to know if the differences between Groups 1 and 2 are statistically significant for both categories (i.e., is 241 significantly different from 135 and same for 40 vs. 16).

Comment: To test differences between groups within a category, use the binomial distribution. To test that groups are different for _both_ categories, I'd assume the categories are independent